# How to activate flash player for a Quickly created webview/webkit app

Tags: 12.04, python, flash, quickly, glade

I created a web browser program using webview/webkit as the web displayer.  I noticed that when I went to youtube only a few videos worked. I am pretty sure that I have to tell webview to activate flash player but I don't know how to do this.

I heard somewhere that it might need to import resources from another browser in order to play flash videos. I don't know if that is true but I would preferably have the flash work without help from any other browser but if it needs to have Firefox installed to play flash then that’s okay too.

I am using quickly which uses glade as the interface designer and python as the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the name of this "web browser program" is?

Comment: ...and what does it have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: I created this web browser program using quickly and webview as the web page displayer

Comment: http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ it has to do with Ubuntu because it was made with quickly, an Ubuntu developer's tool.  the link is a tutorial on creating an Ubuntu program using quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more descriptive.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried asking in UbuntuForums or #ubuntu-app-devel
Application development on Ubuntu in IRC chat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found these commands for terminal.

```
  sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
  sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper
  sudo nspluginwrapper -i /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
  nspluginwrapper -v -a -n -i
```

flash works now.